# How to send multiple responses to one request in Meteor

Tags: meteor, websocket, ddp

I have a piece of code where I use a 3rd party api to get data from, lets say Facebook,

I do the following query

```
Meteor.call('getAwesomeUsers', function() { ... });
```

now on the server this is I have

```
_.each(['zuck','shane', 'dustin'], function(key, value) {
            console.log(key, value)
            var data= HTTP.get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/' ).data; 
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
```

(Please ignore the code, just get the idea of returning the data per user request,)

So as the code shows there are three requests made to the server, I can see the data is grabbed properly using my console.log() but the data is not returned to the client.

All I want to know is how do I send this data down to the client in seperate three times.

**UPDATE**
I just make 3 requests to the server at the moment just to make things work

Answer (score 0):

You can't. This isn't even a question of meteor or javascript, it's a matter of programming paradigm. A function returns only once, not multiple times.

So you have two options:

1. bundle the responses into one
2. create a separate communication that you can use, applying your own logic about when to send something and how to react to receiving data on the other end.

For 1. you can simple do this:

```
return _.map(['zuck','shane', 'dustin'], function(key, value) {
            console.log(key, value)
            var data= HTTP.get( 'https://graph.facebook.com/' ).data; 
            console.log(data);
            return data;
        });
```

which will just give you an array with three "responses".

Comment: thanks@christian , how about if I follow this ? http://meteorcapture.com/publishing-data-from-an-external-api/ I just dont want the client to wait till all three requests are completed on the server.. I need them to see results fast

Comment: ok this is what I did, now I'm doing 3 request to the server, so the server sends one response..

Comment: yes, that referenced solution is definitely a nice one, in the sense that it is very much meteor-style (using a publication). It's just a bit more work.